# Delete millions of rows disabling Indexes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table with millions of rows. I'm deleting `where year(data) in (2013,2014,2015)`. It's taking more than 4hrs. I'm trying now to delete only year 2013 but it's still very very slow (every year has like more than 600.000 rows and it has a `varbinary` column to store .PDF files).

I know that indexes can decrease performance on deletes. It will be a good Idea to `Disable` both indexes in that table, and then re-enable them?

[image]

Can it be faster if I create a view, and delete from the view?

---

Edit:

I made this query to delete it by top 1:

```
delete top (1) from MyTable where year(data) in ( 2013)--,2014,2015)
while @@rowcount > 0
    begin
    delete top (1) from MyTable where year(data) in ( 2013)--,2014,2015)
    end
```

Comment: If these indexes are heavily used by your applications then they will become slow. Also if the indexes are there for 'enforcing' uniqueness then you risk that you cannot enable them afterwards.

Comment: Oh, This database is the development database. But for sure I would like to know how to proceed in a production environment.

Comment: how big are the pdf's?  Keep in mind every row deleted gets written to the log file.  Also, is it a problem for this delete process to take a while?  You could do it in batches, and just let it run.

Comment: Try to create a procedure that loops and delete the rows in small chunks.  Per month or week. You need to commit after each chunk.

Comment: Hey Max. That's not a problem at all. I'm just curious because if sometime I need to do this in production, I can think about the perfect approach. But I made a query to delete it in loops. In another query window, I can see it's deleting. The query is in the Answer as a Edit. But please if you have a better approach, I would be glad to hear.

Comment: Creating an index may actually help you here... if there isn't one on (data). Also rewrite the query to "where data >= '20130101' and data < '20160101'" , which will use an index on (data) if there is one. "Where year(data) in (2013, 2014, 2015)" won't. SQL may be spending (wasting) a lot of time just finding the row it needs to delete. Also think about larger batches than 1 row at a time https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes

Comment: Good point. I'm deleting `in year(data)=2013`. With `2014` I will try `>= and <=`. They have almost the same amount of rows, and I can calculate the time spent in both operations. Thank you.

Comment: What's the table structure including indexes?

Comment: Other considerations: is there a `DELETE` trigger on the table? If so, you could evaluate whether the actions in the trigger are needed. If a trigger is being used to update information in another table, then rebuilding that information when the delete is finished might be a reasonable alternative. Do other tables have foreign keys to this table's primary key, especially with ON DELETE CASCADE enabled? it might be faster to delete the related rows first, then the rows in this table.

Comment: This might help you: http://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how interconnected this table is with others in your database, and assuming that the table only has data for 2013-present, the fastest solution might be:

1. Script out your original table, and create a new empty table with the same structure.
2. `INSERT` the data for 2016 and 2017 into the new table.
3. `DROP` the original table.
4. Rename the new table to the original table's name (see the docs for `ALTER TABLE`).

Deletes are generally enough slower than inserts that it's probably faster to copy out 25-30% of the records in the table than to delete 70-75% of them. However, of course, you need to have sufficient disk space to hold the duplicates of the data to be kept to be able to use this solution (as noted by Toby in the comments).

If you do this, you'll want to be absolutely certain that the new table ends up exactly like the original, including any indexes, triggers, etc. You might want to truncate the original, rename it, and keep it around for a while instead of deleting it, just to be sure there's nothing you've missed. Also, outside of any clustered index, you may want to add clustered indexes and triggers after you've inserted the 2016 and 2017 data. If triggers are involved at all, make sure that whatever you do leaves the rest of your data in a valid state.

If other tables reference your table in foreign key relationships (as suggested by Joe Obbish in the comments), then this becomes somewhat more complicated. I would recommend scripting out all the foreign keys that point to this table, removing them, and then recreating them after the new table has been renamed. See [this link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3347/drop-and-recreate-all-foreign-key-constraints-in-sql-server/?utm_source=dailynewsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_content=headline&utm_campaign=20160818) to an article by Aaron Bertrand for help with this.

Comment: You could use

`SELECT * INTO New_MyTable FROM MyTable WHERE data >= '2016-01-01';
DROP TABLE MyTable`

and then rename the New_MyTable to MyTable

Comment: @Toby - `SELECT ... INTO` wouldn't necessarily capture all aspects of the original table. Indexes, triggers - none of that would come over.

Answer (score 2):

As your trying to delete all data between 01/01/2013 00:00:00 and 31/12/2015 23:59:59, try this

```
delete * from MyTable where data >= '2013-01-01' and data < '2016-01-01'
```

That will allow it to use any available index.

Comment: Agreed.  I'm pretty sure running YEAR() or any other function on the data column in the WHERE clause will cause it to ignore the index on that column.

Comment: Yep I did the year() and it took almost 5hrs. I'm trying now with `>=`. I will post results

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend partitioning your table now.

I'd create a new table partitioned by year that looks just like your current table then insert into it.  Going forward, you can more easily prune your table.

Here are several links to a good partitioning discussions...
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/partitioning-in-sql-server-part-1.html
https://www.datavail.com/blog/four-things-remember-planning-sql-partitioning/

I'm not a SQL Server guy - I saw an MS SQL Server 2016 documentation suggests there are some differences in 2014 features - but I can't find 2014 documentation.

Here is a link to MS SQL Server 2008...
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188706(v=sql.105).aspx

Good luck!